# String as integer variable name

Tags: java, android, string, int

I have `int CYAN` in `Color` class and get requested color from database

```
valueColor = this.getArguments().getString("valueColor", valueColor);
```

that is String `"CYAN"`. How do I use this string as integer variable name in the following example?

```
int[] color = {color.CYAN,Color.WHITE};
```

Comment: are you sure you don't need an Enum?

Comment: then how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the color string, thus:

```
colourString = getArguments().getString("valueColor", colourString);
int valueColor = Color.parseColor(colourString);
```

You may need to `.toLower()` as the docs only lists lower case examples: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)